# Choose only one field

Tags: formula, fields, conditional

I have two fields in an object, I need choose only one of these fields. I tried using:

```
    <apex:inputField label="{!If(lang=='en' ,'Event type','Tipo de evento')}" value="{!If(lang=='en', nl.Event_type__c, nl.Tipo_de_evento__c)}" id="idEvento" />
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure you can use IF statements when binding to a field? I don't think so. Why don't you use two inputText with a "rendered" property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you've tried won't work; expressions end up causing the binding to be read-only. A better choice would be to use a var, and bind using dynamic binding.

```
<apex:var name="eventField" 
    value="{!IF(lang='en', 'Event_Type__c', 'Tipo_de_evento__c')}" />
<apex:inputField label="{!If(lang=='en' ,'Event type','Tipo de evento')}" 
    value="{!nl[eventField]}" id="idEvento" />
```

The "bracket notation" (`[field]`) is used to dynamically reference a field or object. Note that the variable itself must use string values for this to work.

Comment: I don't understand why if I using the field name "Tipo_de_evento__c" is right, but if I use the field name Event_Type__c I got a session error, it's public page.

Thanks a lot

Comment: This 
 
    <apex:var name="eventField" 
    value="{!IF(lang='en', 'Event_Type__c', 'Tipo_de_evento__c')}" />
    <apex:inputField label="{!If(lang=='en' ,'Event type','Tipo de evento')}" 
    value="{!nl[eventField]}" id="idEvento" /> 

Was gold for me, thans a lot, thanks a lot really thanks every body. 

The final error was the "Dependent Fields" fixed the dependences you code save me today, thanks.